# How to get typename aliases from an argument passed via concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Let's take a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
concept Iterable = std::is_same_v<decltype(begin(std::declval<T>())), decltype(end(std::declval<T>()))>;

void print(const Iterable auto& c) {
  std::copy(begin(c), end(c), std::ostream_iterator<???::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
}

int main () {
  std::vector v{{10,20,30,40,50}};
  print(v);
  return 0;
}
```

I wonder what should be written in place of `???::value_type`, since there is no proper type qualification in the definition of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what you mean to do is get the nested typedef of the type, just don't use the abbreviated function template syntax:

```cpp
template <Iterable C>
void print(C const& c) {
    std::copy(begin(c), end(c),
        std::ostream_iterator<typename C::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

This gives you the opportunity to name the type, in a way that `C` isn't even a reference type.

If you really want to stick with the abbreviated function template syntax, you'd have to do this:

```cpp
void print(const Iterable auto& c) {
    using C = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>;
    std::copy(begin(c), end(c),
        std::ostream_iterator<typename C::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

---

Note that you don't need to use `decvlal` with concepts, you can instead use a requires-expression:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Iterable = requires (T t) {
    requires std::is_same_v<decltype(begin(t)), decltype(end(t))>;
};
```

Just a bit better.

Comment: Yes, my aim was to learn how to point out the type not diverting from the non-template style. The idea with `using` and `decltype` somehow slipped my memory. Thank you!